# Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdRequest'

Tags: android, admob

I've switched from Windows to Ubuntu this week. 
I have imported my Android project into Eclipse, and it shows no errors, the project can be built normally.

However, when I try to run the application on a device, the app crashes with the following messages:

> 04-25 14:14:15.700: E/dalvikvm(12640): Could not find class
>   'com.google.ads.AdRequest', referenced from method
>   com.myApp.initAds

and

> 04-25 14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.busybits.treinverkeer-2.apk]
>   04-25 14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):  at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>   04-25 14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) 04-25
>   14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 04-25
>   14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471) 04-25
>   14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   04-25 14:14:15.790: E/AndroidRuntime(12640):  ... 22 more

My build-path is as follows:

- FlurryAgent.jar
- GoogleAdmobAdsSdk-4.1.0.jar
- Android 2.2

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you installed Android SDK 18 or later? If so, check where is your jar files. They should be in project_home/**libs** folder.

Comment: I have installed SDK version 19, there is no `libs` folder in my project home. I removed the jars from the build path, created a `libs` folder and placed the jars in there. Now it works! Quite confusing change if you ask me.. Thanks anyway!